# How to make a page display different things based on user rights?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a page where there's 2 types of users and 1 type gets to do some things while the other one gets to do more. Kind of like 1 user having normal user rights and the other getting admin rights.

Basically, one type of user is a customer, the other type is an admin.

I want my page to show different stuff according to the user type. I know you could do it by just creating separate pages, but I wanna try it this way.

I already have a functional user register page and a functional user login. This page would be what you get after login in

It can only be in JS and HTML.

HTML for the login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <title>Proyecto Final</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="conteiner cf">
                <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
                <nav>
                    <a href="index.html">Usuario</a>
                <!--    <a href="#">About</a> -->
                    <a href="contact.html">Instructor</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>


            <div class="conteiner2 cf">

                <aside class="Texto cf">
                    <h1 class="h1texto">Usuario</h1>


                        <form class="login-form">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="txtUsername"/>

                          <input type="password" placeholder="Password"id="txtPassword"/>

                          <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresarLogin">


                          <p class="message">Estas registrado? <a href="register.html">Crear una nueva cuenta</a></p>
                        </form>

                </aside>

            </div>


    <footer class="footerfinal cf">
            <div class="conteinerfooter cf">
                <p class="ParrafoFooter cf">2014 copyright</p>
                <nav class="NavFooter">
                    <a href="#">Index</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div>

    </footer>
    <script src="js/logicaNegociosUsuarios.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logicaInterfazInicioSesion.js"></script>

    </body>


</html>
```

js for the login

```
document.querySelector('#btnIngresarLogin').addEventListener('click', IniciarSesion);

function IniciarSesion(){
  var sUsername ='';
  var sPassword ='';
  var bAcceso = false;


  sUsername = document.querySelector('#txtUsername').value;
  sPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;


  bAcceso = validarCredenciales(sUsername, sPassword);

  if (bAcceso === true){
    window.location.href = 'perfil.html';
  }
}

function validarCredenciales(psUsername, psPassword){
  var listaUsuarios = obtenerListaUsuarios();
  var bAcceso = false;
  var usuario = obtenerListaUsuarios().map(function (usuario) {
    if(usuario[10] === psUsername){
      if(usuario[11] === psPassword){
        bAcceso = true;
        localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario));
      }
    }
  });
  if(!bAcceso){
    alert('Credenciales incorrectos');
  }
  return bAcceso;
}
```

and the html for the page I want users be redirected to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Perfil</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cédula</td>
                <td id="txtIdentificacion" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1er Nombre</td>
                <td id="txtPrimerNombre" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2ndo Nombre</td>
                <td id="txtSegundoNombre" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1er Apellido</td>
                <td id="txtPrimerApellido" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2ndo Apellido</td>
                <td id="txtSegundoApellido" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nacionalidad</td>
                <td id="txtNacionalidad" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tipo de Identificacion</td>
                <td id="txtTipoIdentificacion" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fecha de Nacimiento</td>
                <td id="datFechaNacimiento" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Edad</td>
                <td id="numEdad" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Género</td>
                <td id="rbtGenero" contenteditable>Cédula</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telefono</td>
                <td id="numNumeroTelefonico" contenteditable></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre de usuario</td>
                <td id="txtNombreUsuario"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Numero de emergencia</td>
                <td id="numEmergencia" contenteditable></td>
            </tr>
                <td>Instructor</td>
                <td id="instructor"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="actualizarDatos">Actualizar</button>
<script src="js/logicaNegociosUsuarios.js"></script>
<script src="js/logicaInterfazPerfil.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

current js for the login:

```
var usuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS'));
document.querySelector('#actualizarDatos').addEventListener('click', actualizarDatos);

llenarDatos();

function llenarDatos(){
    document.querySelector('#txtIdentificacion').innerHTML = usuario[0]
    document.querySelector('#txtPrimerNombre').innerHTML = usuario[1]
    document.querySelector('#txtSegundoNombre').innerHTML = usuario[2]
    document.querySelector('#txtPrimerApellido').innerHTML = usuario[3]
    document.querySelector('#txtSegundoApellido').innerHTML = usuario[4]
    document.querySelector('#txtNacionalidad').innerHTML = usuario[5]
    document.querySelector('#txtTipoIdentificacion').innerHTML = usuario[6]
    document.querySelector('#datFechaNacimiento').innerHTML = usuario[7]
    document.querySelector('#rbtGenero').innerHTML = usuario[8]
    document.querySelector('#numNumeroTelefonico').innerHTML = usuario[9]
    document.querySelector('#txtNombreUsuario').innerHTML = usuario[10]
    document.querySelector('#numEdad').innerHTML = usuario[12];
    document.querySelector('#numEmergencia').innerHTML = usuario[14]
    document.querySelector('#instructor').innerHTML = usuario[15]
}

function actualizarDatos(){
    usuario[0] = document.querySelector('#txtIdentificacion').innerHTML;
    usuario[1] = document.querySelector('#txtPrimerNombre').innerHTML;
    usuario[2] = document.querySelector('#txtSegundoNombre').innerHTML;
    usuario[3] = document.querySelector('#txtPrimerApellido').innerHTML;
    usuario[4] = document.querySelector('#txtSegundoApellido').innerHTML;
    usuario[5] = document.querySelector('#txtNacionalidad').innerHTML;
    usuario[6] = document.querySelector('#txtTipoIdentificacion').innerHTML;
    usuario[7] = document.querySelector('#datFechaNacimiento').innerHTML;
    usuario[8] = document.querySelector('#rbtGenero').innerHTML;
    usuario[9] = document.querySelector('#numNumeroTelefonico').innerHTML;
    usuario[10] = document.querySelector('#txtNombreUsuario').innerHTML;
    usuario[12] = document.querySelector('#numEdad').innerHTML;
    usuario[14] = document.querySelector('#numEmergencia').innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario));
    alert('Usuario actualizado')
}
```

Comment: You should really consider using both a database and a back-end language for this (such as PHP, Python, Java or C#). For your JavaScript, do you run Node.js? Also, what is your code for the login process?

Comment: Voting to close as _"too broad"_.

Comment: Rules are it has to be js and html only. do you think it would be best to simply make more html pages? I have added the code to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

If your limitation is set as only HTML/JS, then you can use `document.cookie` and set cookies for users based on whether they are admin or customer. Then you can check cookies and the render the page conditionally based on user type.

Read more about implementing `document.cookie` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).